# How to group_by and summarize with list column dbplyr

Tags: r, dbplyr

I'm hoping to do the following in a database, but it is does not appear to be possible using {`dbplyr`}. Is there another way? Thank you

```r
library(dbplyr)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dbplyr':
#> 
#>     ident, sql
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

# Desired Behavior
tbl <- tibble(g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), x = c(4, 3, 6, 9, 2))
tbl %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarize(list_x = list(x))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       g list_x   
#>   <dbl> <list>   
#> 1     1 <dbl [3]>
#> 2     2 <dbl [2]>

# Current behavior
db <- memdb_frame(g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), x = c(4, 3, 6, 9, 2))
db %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarize(list_x = list(x))
#> Error: no such function: list
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I don't know of any databases that have a internal concept of `list` - that is an R concept, not a db concept, so I doubt it will automatically translate from R to a database.

Comment: You could concatenate values in a string, depending on your database, it might support JSON entries, there may be other solutions, but we'll need details about what database you're using and why you want to do this - what's your goal, what's the point?

Comment: I'm using MSSQL Server. I wanted to join two tables, and filter out elements from the first table which were not in the list of possible values of a variable from the second. If my SQL were better, I know there are probably ways to do it, but that is harder question for me to formulate in this forum.

Comment: Well, this way won't work. I would suggest working on articulating the problem rather than this solution attempt, otherwise we're left with an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 0):

The best you can probably do is concatenate all the text into a string. Something like:

```r
db <- memdb_frame(g = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2), x = c(4, 3, 6, 9, 2))
db %>%
  group_by(g) %>%
  summarize(list_x = paste0(x, collapse = "|"))
```

You can then search this new column as text rather than as list. For example:

```r
db %>% mutate(indicator = ifelse(grepl('4', list_x), 1, 0))
```